# Iniciar com Tela Splash

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragment

Tenho um projeto e utilizo o Navigation Drawer Activity, e houve a necessidade de colocar uma tela de Splash no inicio do projeto, tentei colocar e agora está dando um erro ao abrir o projeto.

Criei uma `Activity` para ser a telaSplash:

```
public class TelaSplash extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_tela_splash);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

}
```

O Layout da tela:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TelaSplash">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/background_tela_splash" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Alterei também o Manifest para colocar a activity como LAUNCHER:
O `MainActivity` é o principal do `Drawer Activity` e a `TelaSplash` foi o criado.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".TelaSplash"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

E aqui o Logcat do erro:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.expresso1002/com.example.expresso1002.TelaSplash}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1225)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1041)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.expresso1002.TelaSplash.onCreate(TelaSplash.java:16)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1225) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1041) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao usar o tema *AppTheme.NoActionBar* já de cara sua activity não terá uma barra de ferramentas (onde fica o título). Então `getSupportActionBar()` retornará null, a não ser, é claro, que você tenha chamado setSupportActionBar(toolbar) antes.

O que eu tenho a sugerir é não fazer a TelaSplash herdar de `AppCompatActivity` e usar a Activity ordinária em seu lugar. Algumas mudanças se aplicam quando isso é feito, por exemplo, não há *supportActionBar*. Já que é um splash, é interessante ser em "tela cheia", mas preservando as barras do sistema (de status e de navegação).

#### AndroidManifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".TelaSplash"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

#### TelaSplash.java

```
public class TelaSplash extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_tela_splash);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            // Pintar a barra de status
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
        }

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

}
```

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou 100%.

Comment: Não entendi a parte de usar a Activity ordinária, o que seria ?

Comment: `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity` – Classe base para atividades que usam os recursos da barra de ação da biblioteca de suporte vs a "ordinária" (normal) `android.app.Activity`

Comment: Massa, vlw mesmo.